# Why numpy.ndarray.data is toggle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm using python 3.6.7 create a 1-D array, and print its data attribute, and found it is toggle.

But why?

```
>>> a = np.arange(12)
>>> print(a)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fef79ae8f48>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fef79505048> 
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7fef79ae8f48>
```

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks all, it is indeed duplicate. Thanks for letting me see the answer so soon.

Comment: You're welcome, good hunting.